# read line on Gideros without carriage return

Tags: file, lua, line, gideros, lua-edit

I tested the following code on LuaEdit and stores a string just like I want it.

```
local lineVal = myFile:read("*line")
```

However when I test it in Gideros, it stores a string with the line plus a carriage return, which I don't need. How do I get only the strings on the line without the carriage return?

Please help.

Comment: Could this be a problem of line endings being different on linux vs windows?

Comment: I don't know, my OS is windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the output is giving you a carriage return you're not expecting you could always use `gsub` to get rid of it.

`lineval = string.gsub(lineval,"\r","")`